# ERC20 Interfaces overwriting ERC721 functions - Possible to adhere to standard?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-721, interfaces

Is it possible to have a contract that both generates and manages its own NFT according to the `ERC721` Standard, and is able to make calls to outside `ERC20` contracts? My contract currently inherits the ERC20 interface or contract, so that it can calls an instance of ERC20

```
someCoin = ERCInterface(xxxxxx); 
myCoin.transferFrom();
```

However, the `approve()` and `transferFrom()` functions have the exact same number and types of arguments in both standards so the ERC721 functions get overwritten. Does anyone know of a workaround? Alternatively, can someone provide an example of how a direct contract call can be written? Thanks

Comment: Why are you inheriting the ERC20 interface? It sounds like you need to call out to external contracts that follow that interface. No need to inherit it for that, just import the interface, cast the external address, and make the call.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. What is the difference between an import and inheriting?

Comment: It's hard to answer that because the two are unrelated. Importing a file is like copy/pasting the code from that file. Inheritance is a concept from object-oriented programming where a new class/contract is based on the implementation of another one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 1):

One contract cannot simultaneously implement ERC-20 and ERC-721. You must design your system so that those are separate contracts (deployed at separate addresses).

Yes, you can have a ERC-721 contract make calls to an ERC-20 contracts. There is nothing that makes that a problem.

Comment: Actually, single contract may simultaneously implement both: ERC-20 and ERC-721.  The only common method signature is `balanceOf(address)` and its return type is the same for both ERCs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to inherit an interface in order to call its methods:

```solidity
interface Foo {
  function doFoo () external;
}

contract Bar {
  function bar (Foo foo) public {
    foo.doFoo ();
  }
}
```

You need to inherit an interface only when you want you contract to implement this interface by itself:

```solidity
contract MyFoo is Foo {
  function doFoo () public {
    // Do something useful here
  }
}
```